# What is the definition for an interval in a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Tags: number-theory

I read in some number theory papers about interval in finite field. For example one such interval is $\{1,2,...,N\}$ of $N$ consecutive residues modulo $p$. Does there exists other kind of interval also? I am curious to know about the proper definition of an interval in a finite field.

Comment: I am also curious. An interval is not defined for finite fields. Can you give a link?

Comment: You can define intervals in any partial ordered set easily and consistently. But the same definition does not works for finite fields as they not ordered.

Comment: [See here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356188/what-happens-if-you-strip-everything-but-the-between-relation-in-metric-spaces) for an attempt extend intervals on metric spaces.